# Close the application on back button of android phones

Tags: android, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm developing a app using angularjs and ionic framework. It has a logout option also. When i logout from my app it goes straight to the home page.But if i press the back button it'll go to page that can be accessed only if you are logged in. How can i create a option to close the app if you press the back button from the home page? I use angularjs.

I used this way but did not work

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e){
    if($.mobile.activePage.is('/templates/playlists')){
        /* 
         Event preventDefault/stopPropagation not required as adding backbutton
          listener itself override the default behaviour. Refer below PhoneGap link.
        */
        //e.preventDefault();
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
    else {
        navigator.app.backHistory()
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good.

But, I'm not sure about the second line : are you sure that the active page id is `/templates/playlists` ?

Normally, the value you should pass to the `$.mobile.activePage.is` function should contain a page id (which could be retrieved like this : `$.mobile.activePage.attr('id')`).

(by the way, I don't know which of jQuery Mobile you are using, but the `$.mobile.activePage.is` was deprecated).

Comment: I dont think the issue is with active id page.Because when i run with this code on,it shows a black screen(meaning script error).I can use this with angularjs right? if so where should i apply it?